# Why say "Stack Overflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging framework" when asked to reason a script behavour?

Tags: discussion, support

I would like to describe a concern I faced while I posted a question yesterday. I was experimenting on a small JavaScript snippet and got into a situation where I could not reason the behavior.

I defined a function and wrote a self-executing function along side it which had nothing inside it. The script block, while executed, was triggering the first function which I didn't trigger anywhere in my code. I needed to reason the situation, so that I could understand what was happening with it when it gets executed.

So I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884081/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-in-javascript-code-block) on Stack Overflow. I got quite good replies and one of them properly explained the exactly situation where how that code gets converted when we miss a semicolon for the function expression.

The problem I need to point out is the downvote and comment rant I got for the question saying

> Stack Overflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging framework

by most of the comments. And I even asked them to reason it, when OP asks with a code block to reason a particular behavior, how come it can be considered as a debugging request? I didn't get proper responses to the same. The comments which are made are still on the question. Even you can see there are three close requests to close it saying it's a debugging request which is not accepted on Stack Overflow.

Can any one throw some lights on what exactly is the reason it's not suited for the site? Also, when people are not replying back and you receive such hatred, is flagging the question for moderator attention, the only way to get some reply on my question? This is not a complaint. But it will help me ask better questions in the future.

#### Side note:

To add to this problem, look at one of the comments on the question

> I just googled OPs error message and the first result is a SO link
> with the answer.

Does googling for the error message and getting a solution for another case has anything to do with considering it as a bad question. In fact, he was saying `“Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function”` had an answer when he googled it. But my question is, look at the code block; there are no function calls which corresponds to that and that is what I am asking you for the support.

Comment: In light of your post and supporting code and explanation ... something a bit malicious about the accusation actually from terex, but nevermind. yeah just ignore it.  mistakes happen

Comment: And *actually*, StackOverflow is very much *a crowd-sourced debugging framework* , as long as the user asks nicely enough, with demonstrable effort beforehand(ie not code-dumps ). At least, it has been a huge debugging-aid for me :)

Comment: I guess the problem of downvotes is solved now. _Yay_ meta effect.

Comment: Your issue is very specific. The question can only serve to help you and to entertain answerers. It will help no one else in the future. There is an infinite number of possible questions like this one. Someone could write a programmatic question generator and have it post 10 per day to Stack Overflow. That generator would generate a program, run it and ask "Why does the program {sourceCode} print {observedOutput}?".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I already stated this in the comments yesterday, and I'll repeat it here.

You didn't post a code dump saying "my code doesn't work, please fix it". Your question is fine. It could be closed with the *simple typographical error* reason, but I'm not entirely convinced that the *unlikely to help future readers* part of that close reason applies here.

Ignore the comment and the attached close votes. They're nonsense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25884081/1

Comment: @gnat I've seen the first revision and it doesn't change my opinion.

Answer (score 20):

The fact that a question can be interpreted and (guess-)answered by those willing to, does not mean it is a *good* question considering the [Stack Overflow guidelines for asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a point often overlooked by those defending any (not specifically your) question.

On the other hand, a good (or at least not *bad*) but often asked question, or one with an obvious answer, can be considered to be less than welcome on the site by those who immediately spot the error and know the answer. Your question was closed by five relatively high-rep users, who would appear to have at least any experience on the matter, thus deeming your question off-topic for being trivial and unhelpful.

Part of this boils down to a matter of wording. I cannot see that specifically into the vote history, but your question at first was titled "Issue with JavaScript code block". **At that first revision, your question *was* a code dump with an undescriptive title, asking *"Why doesn't this work"***. That is not an adequate problem description and it does not show at all what you have tried, what you expect this code to do or why you think it does that. That is not the kind of question that is deemed "good" on Stack Overflow, hence the close- and downvotes. I don't know why a moderator removed your addition that linked to a totally relevant question, where the problem of semicolons was mentioned.

All the relevant information, making it a better question, was added in later revisions, while your question kept on gathering close- and downvotes. The final close vote occurred after your latest edit, only at which moment it (in my opinion) didn't deserve anymore to be closed.

Here's an attempt at a different phrasing of the same problem:

---

I have those two JavaScript code blocks. I would expect it only to show "Bar" in the log, because nowhere do I call `b()`. Yet it shows "Foo" followed by "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

```
var b = function() {
  console.log('Foo');
}

(function() { 
  console.log('Bar');
})();
```

Searching the web for said error I found the question [Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on loading jquery-min.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js), where it is mentioned that concatenating blocks of JavaScript code should be separated by semicolons.

Is this relevant to my problem, and if so, where would I need to insert this semicolon?

---

I hope the difference between this and your initial question is clear, and will help you towards asking better questions in the future.

Comment: I don't want to continue this discussion in comments and will remove my comments. Everything relevant I wanted to say is in my answer, feel free to read it again.

Comment: Just want to point out to one huge flaw with this answer. A code dump is far more than a small reproducible snippet of code not work. The user in question here already reduced the problem to just 5 lines of code and at that point if you miss the error he could do no more. Describing what he expects the code to do is entirely redundant as it's clear for both beginner and adept alike. Even your linked answer doesn't explain the semicolon issue and so it makes sense that it would not seem relevant whilst debugging such an issue as a beginner.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Please read the comments I put above related to wrong facts in your question. It would be great if you respond to them in your answer.

Answer (score 20):

Considering you have reserved a nice side note for a comment I wrote I will explain my comment.

The reason I downvoted your question and added my comment is because I indeed googled your exact error message and the first result on the page came up with the semicolon issue.

> Does googling for the error message and getting a solution for another case has anything to do with considering it as a bad question

It shows lack of (any) effort.

And now you are saying: "I knew it was the semicolon, I asked about why it does it!"

Well let me do the same thing I did yesterday and see what the first result comes up with:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+semicolon

Which results in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript/1834674#1834674) with... your exact problem including an explanation.

So again (imho): serious lack of effort.

Comment: Now, if you had been a little nicer, this would probably get a lot more votes as it is actually correct. Sorry mate.

Comment: I'm sorry if my message isn't wrapped in a nice fluffy velvet blanket of love @felixphew :-) I actually hesitated to even post this because posts like this are hard to not be taken the wrong way. I merely tried to explain my stance on OPs explanation of the situation :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yes. I agree with your point that if if I could have got to the qn you mention, then I wont be puting the mentioned question. But I couldn't get to it doesnt mean I dint do research. I threw many searches before I put my question.